# Class object property which references another object instance of same object type

Tags: vb.net

I have a class object which looks like this:

```vb
Public Class item
    Public Property ID
    Public Property Name
    Public Property Description
    Public Property Type
    Public Property Alias
End Class
```

I am currently storing these as a dictionary like this:

```vb
Public Class Items

    Public ReadOnly dict Dictionary(Of String, item) From {
        {"A", New item With {.Name = "Object A", .Description = "Object A description"}},
        {"B", New item With {.Name = "Object B", .Description = "Object B description"}},
        {"C", New item With {.Alias = "A"}}
    }

    Public Function GetItem(ByVal ID As String) As item
        Return If(dict.ContainsKey(ID), idct.Item(ID), Nothing)
    End Function

End Class
```

The complexity is that sometimes an `item` will not have any properties itself but instead has an `.Alias` property which says "All of my properties are the same as `item` with this ID, check that object instead".

How should I write my class object `item` so that this code returns "Object A":

```vb
Dim newItem As item = GetItem("C")
Debug.WriteLine(item.Name)
```

Object C is an alias of Object A so I should return some properties (not always all of them) for Object A instead of `Nothing`.

A way around this is by adding the below function to the `Items` class:

```vb
Public Function GetItemDescription(ByVal ID As String) As String
    If dict.ContainsKey(ID) Then
        If dict.Item(ID).Description = "" Then
            Return GetItemDescription(dict.Item(ID).Alias)
        Else
            Return dict.Item(ID).Description
        End If
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

However this doesn't feel like the correct way as then I have to repeatedly call a set of `Items.GetPropertyXYZ` functions rather than directly referencing the object (e.g. `item.Description` would have to be `GetItemDescription("C")`

Is my solution acceptable from a design persepctive, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetItem(ByVal [alias] As String) As item
    Return dict.Where(Function(a) a.Key = [alias]).Select(Function(b) b.Value).FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

---

**Edit 1**

Certainly it returns the "C" item because its wrong. Sorry.

This one works (Tested):

```
Public Function GetItem(ByVal ID As String) As item
    Dim itm As item = dict.Where(Function(a) a.Key = ID).Select(Function(b) b.Value).FirstOrDefault

    Return If(itm IsNot Nothing, If(itm.Alias IsNot Nothing, dict(itm.Alias), itm), Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. It still returns Object C. I wondered if could some similar code like the `GetItemDescription` function in my question, but in the property Get?

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to mark this as the answer because it does work, however I've also posted the solution I ended up with after I'd slept on it. It meets my requirements more closely.

Answer (score 1):

JQSOFT's answer does achieve a similar thing, however I've since realised a more granular way I can achieve the same result.

```vb
Private Property _description As String
Public Property Description As String
    Get
        If _Description = "" Then
            If [Alias] IsNot Nothing Then
                Return dict.Item([Alias]).Description
            Else
                Return ""
            End If
        Else
            Return _description 
        End If
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _description = value
    End Set
End Property
```

This way allows me to specify whether I return the data from `Object A` at property level, rather than returning an entirely different object.

Also, `.Alias` is a terrible property name as it's also a keyword, I'm going to use `.Synonym`.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you then have to forward every property.  Depending on the context, this is the sort of thing where it could be helpful to use generated code instead of hand-copying everything.

Comment: This is true, and why I marked JQSOFT's version as the answer as it avoids that.  The reason this is more useful in my use case is because not all properties need to be forwarded when an alias exists. For example, `.Name` and `.Description` might be unique, but `.Type` might be inherited from the specified `.Alias`. I'm sure there must be better ways to store this information but it's provided in that format so I don't have much choice.

Comment: Indeed, and having that downside doesn't mean (as you note) that it's unsuitable.  I mainly commented to point out that generated code can help with a situation where you have a lot of boilerplate (if it's only two or three properties forwarded, then copy-and-paste makes more sense).